# getting the value of the selected DropDown menu option

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

So i know there have been many posts about this and ive read them, but the solutions recommended in this previous posts, dont work.

I have a function that dynamically creates me a drop down menu. Here it is:

```
function date(start, end) {

    output ="";
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
    output += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
    }

    document.write(output);

}
```

And i call it like this:

```
Month:
        <select name="mm" id="mm" disabled onchange="activateDate();">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                date(1,12);
            </script>
        </select>
```

Note: activateDay just changes the attribute disabled in the next dropdown menu, because you should first select a year, then a month, then a day.

and when i try to get the selected value of the month so that i can give a month a number of days (31 for january, 28 for february)like this :

```
var a = document.getElementById("mm");
var month = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
```

And if i use this vars for a switch which looks for the month and returns the number of the days, then i give the number of days to my `date()` i get an empty drop down menu for my dates. The Javascript console in chrome says this:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null**

And points me to this line:

```
var month = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
```

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should avoid `document.write`. See warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29)

Comment: yeah i know but our teacher told us to use it, ive already heard this a lot...

Comment: With a teacher like this, I would try getting my money back, and go to another course

Comment: im in a public school...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
Cannot read property 'options' of null
```

means that `a` is null in `a.options[a.selectedIndex].value`.

Since you have an element with `id="mm"`, check if:

- Some script has hijacked `window.document`
- Some script has hijacked `document.getElementById`
- Some script has deleted your select, or changed its `id`
- You use `var a = document.getElementById("mm")` before loading the select to the DOM

Probably its the last one, try running your code at `onload` event, or place your script just before closing `</body>`.

Comment: What do you mean by hijacked ?

Comment: @Jakob I mean `document.getElementById = function(){ return null; }`

Comment: and using onload would make no sense for me, because i dont know which month the user wants to choose when the file is loading

Comment: @Jakob I don't understand. You know the month during document load, but don't know it once loaded?

Comment: i dont understand your code when i call my function that u name function i need the month as parameter. why should i call it in the `document.getElementById` and how should this works.

Comment: @Jakob No, that was only an example of hijacking `getElementById`. Don't do that. Try placing your script just before closing `</body>` instead.

Comment: @Orial oh ok :D and your question that i know the month. When the page loads there are 3 drop down list. one for year, one for month one for day. Just year is enabled. when you picked a year drop down month is enabled too, but day still disabled. so now AFTER you picked the month the day should be enabled and u  can choose. this is working but now i have to give the day a dynamic number of options because not every month has the same days.

Comment: @Jakob But then you could run your initial code in `onload` event

Comment: @Jakob The code which runs at the beginning (as opposed to the code which runs in events or timeouts). Usually, this code is placed inside an `init` function, which is set as event listener of `load` or called just before `</body>`

Comment: i dont understand what this should do then. i need to change the day drop down AFTER the month drop down has been used. i dont know how to do this...

Comment: i somehow need to get the value of the month dropdown after changing it (with onchange would be the best i think) and then change they day drop down. but i have 2 problems: 1. i cant get the value of month 2. i dont know how to change the day drop down then

Comment: @Jakob Can you post full code in order to see where you use each code?

Comment: i just fixed it. i know what the problem was. you already said it was a bad idea. document.write didnt work properly i think with inner html it works good. my teacher isnt gonna love my work but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
var month = a.options[a.selectedIndex-1].value;
```

Comment: `a` is null as said in the log

Comment: if u mean `var month = a.options[0,options.length].value;` thats not working too

Comment: @Jakob No, I mean mathematical interval `[0,options.length) = {0,1,...,options.length-1}`. Then, subtracting `1` is nonsense.